# Microsoft QnA for analytics

Tags: powerbi, azure-qna-maker

I have a WPF application which has lot of canned queries. Recently, I came across Power BI QnA and its very impressive.

I would like to know, if Microsoft QnA maker provides similar capability which can be integrated with .Net applications. This would help to make the query feature more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the capabilities of Power BI QnA in your .net application using Power BI Embedded QnA:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/qanda

browse the capabilities Power BI Embedded gives you in: http://aka.ms/pbijs

Also, you can attach Bot Framework to display a Power BI Embedded Report (or QnA).
Note that in the near future there is probably going to be access to a REST API providing you the ability to use it anyway you'd like, including QnA Maker